# `telegraf help` on command line gives error

Tags: macos, homebrew, influxdb

I installed telegraf using homebrew on MacOS and ran the generator:

Now `telegraf help` gives the error:

> No config file specified, and could not find one in $TELEGRAF_CONFIG_PATH, /Users/**Username**/.telegraf/telegraf.conf, or /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf

There is no location /etc/telegraf. There is no directory /~.telegraf either.

This seems to be an error with the telegraf installation script. Homebrew installs telegraf to

> /usr/local/Cellar/telegraf/0.13.1/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
find /usr $HOME -name telegraf.conf
```

to see where `homebrew` has created it and then set `TELEGRAF_CONFIG_PATH` to match.

Comment: /usr/local/etc/telegraf.conf